# Access Json collection returned from Kendo Upload Complete function

Tags: c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller, kendo-upload

Wrapping my head around this for the last two hours and I cannot seem to figure it out. All I'm trying to do is access a collection in a response from a `Controller` that is sent via the `Kendo Uploader`.

Any help, Greatly appreciated!

**The code:**

```
$("...").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: "...",
                removeUrl: "...",
                autoUpload: true
            },
            complete: function (e) {
                onKendoDocSuccess(e, '@Model.FieldValue.Id');

                $.each(e.response, function (index, value) {
                    alert(value.FileName);
                    var html = "<div class='fieldvaluedocument' data-fieldvalueid='@Model.FieldValue.Id'> " +
                                    "<a href='#' title=''>" + value.FileName + "(" + value.SizeInKb + "Kb)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
                               "</div>";

                    $('.js-list-files').prepend(html);
                });
            },
```

The return in the controller:

```
return Json(new { uploadedContent = uploadedFile}, "text/plain");
```

`uploadedContent` is a collection.

[image]

Iv'e tried numerous ways to try and access the collection in JavaScript but either I get undefined, Token not recognized etc.

Iv'e never had this much trouble before, I must be missing the obvious.

Appreciate your time.

Regards,

Comment: Why is this here? "text/plain"  I don't normally see this in JSON responses.

Comment: "text/plain" is per kendo documentation. Snippet from docs: **// When returning JSON the mime-type must be set to text/plain
    return Json(new { status = "OK" }, "text/plain");**

Comment: okay cool, and where are you trying to read the response? The complete? I see examples for processing that metadata for success, but not complete. The docs for complete don't tell us much about the argument, unfortunately, or I'm missing it

Comment: I'm not positive the complete event has the same response that success does? If you use console, are you getting the actual response in there? I'm looking at this http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/events  also this http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/upload/metadata#receiving-metadata-from-the-save-handler

Comment: Tried Success and Complete...Console displays nothing but I see it in my response. Driving me bonkers, the documentation is very poor. Ok, A little more digging and Iv'e found it throws errors in jquery 2.+. Compatibility issue, who knows. More digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to parse Json, then you can access collection, etc.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
```

Comment: Interesting, maybe its malformed json, take the json response and run it through json viewer, I use this site http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you have your answer yet, but I faced this problem today.

I couldn't access the collection in the success function. So, I created an error function to see if there was something wrong: And there was.

So, through the error function, I used ***`e.XMLHttpRequest.response`*** to access the collection and it worked.

Hope it helps you, too.